# Update image in ViewModel2 when it is changed in ViewModel1

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have the following setup (this is my first foray into MVVM and I am trying to switch over from using code-behind):

I have `Contact`s. There is a window showing all the contacts. On the left side is a `ListView` that has a list of `ContactCard` each `ContactCard` can have an image.

To the right of the list is a `ContactDataDisplay` which shows all the information about the selected contact including the same image as in the `ContactCard`. Inside the `ContactDataDisplay` is an `EditableImage`. These are just images that are overlayed with 2 buttons, "Update" and "Remove", when the user hovers over the image. The `EditableImage` has its own ViewModel (as it shouldn't be tied to only `Contact`s

I have it wired up properly so that the image updates in the `ContactDataDisplay` using bindings, (which is easy since it all occurs in the same ViewModel). However, I am stuck on how I can get the `ContactCard` image to update considering that it has an entirely separate ViewModel.

I tried to add a click listener to the button in the `EditableImage` and update the `ContactCard` with the new image in code behind, but I can't force the order of the method call as far as I know, and this seems to go against the point of MVVM.

How do I connect my `ContactCardViewModel` and my `EditableImageViewModel` so that the `ContactCard` image changes, without passing the actual `Contact` object that is being bound to in my `ContactCardViewModel`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using Event Aggregator Pattern.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23314.using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models.aspx

In this case ViewModel1 will be the publisher and ViewModel2 the subscriber.